# Creates a Git repo by default?

Tags: angular-cli

I dont want to use a Git repo, but im curious why cli would try to set this as a default and if so, what does it create locally within the project structure - compared to when you run --skip-git?

Im using the --dry-run flag and seeing what is listed, then adding on the --skip-git flag, trying to see whats different.  I dont really see any differences.  What am I missing?  Im using Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

You're probably under UNIX file system hence the `.git` is not listed.

The --skip-git flag will not create a repository and any repository has all the information inside the `.git` directory. If you do `ls -a` under your project directory probably will notes the difference.

On Windows this folder is also marked as hidden, if you change folder setting to see all the files you will see the git directory.

You can simply remove this directory if it wasn't your intention or run `git init` if you regret from skipping it.

Comment: The `.gitignore` file is generated too and comes pre-loaded with recommended ignore patterns and files too.